# Add annotation pin on touch using MapKit and UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer, mkannotation

I have some problems with adding annotations when the user touch the map.

I'm using `UIGestureRecognizer` to detect the user's touch.

When a long press is detected, I'm calling this function :

```
- (void)handleLongPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) return;

NSLog(@"long press");

CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:mapView];   
CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = 
[mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

RdvAnnotation *rdvAnnotation = [[RdvAnnotation alloc] init];

[rdvAnnotation initWithCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate];

[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]; 

[mapView addAnnotation:rdvAnnotation];

[rdvAnnotation release]; }
```

I cans see the NSLog in the console and the `rdvAnnotation` is initialized with the good coordinate.

I don't understand why I can't see my annotation on the map.

Here's my `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[RdvAnnotation class]]) 
{
    static NSString* RdvAnnotationIdentifier = @"rdvAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)
    [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:RdvAnnotationIdentifier];

    if (!pinView)
    {
        MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                               initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:RdvAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        return customPinView;

    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}
return nil;}
```

My `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setDelegate:self];

CLLocationManager *locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

[locationManager setDelegate:self];

[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

self.navigationItem.title = @"Rendez-vous" ;    
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the `-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` MapView delegate ? This is where the actual view gets created.

Comment: Yes I did, I have updated my question. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Seems to be ok. Could it be something related to gesture location to coordinates conversion ? Can you check if the coordinates are in the visible area for the mapview ?

Comment: Checked it, it is. I also tried with zoom out at the maximum, can't see the annotation anywhere. I can't figure out what the problem is. Is there anywhere else (in the code) I should check ?

Comment: How is mapView declared and created?  Show how the gesture recognizer is added to the map view.  After the addAnnotation line, put `NSLog(@"ann count = %d", mapView.annotations.count);` and see what it says.  Do you call removeAnnotation(s) anywhere else in the code?

Comment: The gesture recognizer is added in Interface Builder. the NSLog says 1 (so there's not my new annotation). RemoveAnnotation is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed something that seems weird :

```
RdvAnnotation *rdvAnnotation = [[RdvAnnotation alloc] init];
[rdvAnnotation initWithCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate];
```

You're calling init twice on the annotation object. You should just do it this way :

```
RdvAnnotation *rdvAnnotation = [[RdvAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate]];
```

**EDIT :** 
If you have code in your init method that you don't want to lose, keep the init and change the value of the coordinate property :

```
RdvAnnotation *rdvAnnotation = [[RdvAnnotation alloc] init];
rdvAnnotation.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
```

Comment: I fixed this error, but it didn't solved my problem. Still don't have my new annotation. In fact, the first init initialized my object and the second put the right coordinate in my object.

Comment: If you had important code in the overloaded init, you try what I suggested in my edit in the answer.

Comment: Also tried with that, but still nothing. However, I very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` you are creating a new map view object.

First, this new map view object is not being added as a subview to `self.view` so it exists in memory but is invisible.

Second, you probably already have a map view object placed in the view in Interface Builder so you don't need to create a new one.

So what is probably happening is that when you add the annotation, it is being added to the map view object in memory but not the one that is visible (the one that was created in IB).

Instead of creating a new map view in `viewDidLoad`, connect the `mapView` IBOutlet to the map view in Interface Builder.

Comment: Ok, so I've removed the declaration on mapView in ViewDidLoad. The mapView is well connected in IB, but I still can't see new annotations.

Comment: In the .h, do you have mapView defined as `@property (retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;` and in IB, is the `mapView` outlet in File's Owner connected to the map view?  Are the NSLogs in the gesture recognizers still showing and does the count show?

Comment: In the .h mapView is defined as @property (retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView; and in IB the mapView outlet is connected to the map view. The count increase when a press on the map ( i've removed the removeAnnotation ).

Comment: There is only one map view in the xib, right?  What happens if you temporarily comment out the viewForAnnotation delegate method (map view should put red pin by default)?  What if you manually add an annotation with some specific coordinates in viewDidLoad (not in the gesture recognizer)?

Comment: Yes, only one. If i comment out the viewForAnnotation delegate method, it doesn't change anything. When i add manually an annotation, it is not displayed, but the count of annotation is good ( it says 3 after a press : my position, the annotation added manually and the annotation after the press)

Comment: So you see the map but no blue dot and none of your annotations even though the count is correct.  Do the annotations suddenly appear after you scroll the map?  Does Apple's sample app MapCallouts work for you (with no changes)?

Comment: Sorry, i see the blue dot , but only this one. Scrolling the map doesn't make any changes. Yes MapCallouts work perfectly for me.

Comment: In viewDidLoad, add an annotation like this: `MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; pa.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51, 0); [mapView addAnnotation:pa];`.  Do you see a red pin near London?  If yes, there might be a problem in your annotation class' init method.

Comment: Yes I can see it, so i'll check my annotation class

Comment: I replace in my code:
 RdvAnnotation *rdvAnnotation = [[RdvAnnotation alloc] init];
by :
  MKPointAnnotation *rdvAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
and it's working perfectly, so i'll check out my annotation class.
Thanks a lot Anna, i can now continue my project.